# could not able to get the list of values, images from firebase in fragment activity

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, kotlin

I could not able to retrieve data from firebase. While retrieving the data getting the below error. Kindly help!

```
 2020-12-11 16:53:09.370 14410-14410/com.troll.trollmemes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.troll.trollmemes, PID: 14410
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.troll.trollmemes.Fragment.HomeFragment$2.onDataChange(HomeFragment.java:97)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Code:

```js
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    postList.clear();
    for (@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
      for (String id: followingList) {
        if (post.getPublisher().equals(id)) {
          postList.add(post);
        }
        postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
```

Comment: public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postList.clear();
                for (@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    for (String id : followingList){
                        if (post.getPublisher().equals(id)){
                            postList.add(post);
                        }
                        postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=Attempt+to+invoke+virtual+method+%27boolean+java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)%27+on+a+null+object+reference+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Please [Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=Attempt+to+invoke+virtual+method+%27boolean+java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)%27+on+a+null+object+reference+site:stackoverflow.com) before asking